# get less correlated variable names

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataset (50 columns, 100 rows).
Also have 50 variable names, 0,1,2...49 for 50 columns.
I have to find less correlated variables, say correlation < 0.7.
I tried as follows:

```
import os, glob, time, numpy as np, pandas as pd
data = np.random.randint(1,99,size=(100, 50))
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (dataframe.shape)

codes = np.arange(50).astype(str)
dataframe.columns = codes

corr = dataframe.corr()
corr = corr.unstack().sort_values()
print (corr)
corr = corr.values
indices = np.where(corr < 0.7)
print (indices)
res = codes[indices[0]].tolist() + codes[indices[1]].tolist()
print (len(res))
res = list(set(res))
print (len(res))
```

The result is, 50(all variables!), which is unexpected.
How to solve this problem, guys?

Comment: What makes you sure that a correlation exists? Have you introduced one column that is clearly correlated to another one to see, if this columns will not appear in your index list? You should also work with `abs(corr)`, because a correlation of -1 is <0.7, but not what you try to extract.

Comment: The correlation of variable names is not something that has any reasonable definition. Also, in your example, `outs` is undefined. I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: @AmiTavory outs is data, sorry for typo error

Comment: Have you tried exactly the posted code? You should get an error message, because you unstack, for whatever reason, the correlation matrix and use the index of the longer 1D array on the columns and rows of the 2D dataframe. That doesn't work, does it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your question is somewhat ambiguous. First, there is the possibility, that no column pair is correlated. Second, the unstacking doesn't make sense, because you create an index array that you can't directly use on your 2D array. Third, which should be first, but I was blind to this - as @AmiTavory mentioned there is no point in "correlating names".

The correlation procedure *per se* works, as you can see in the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.arange(100).reshape(25, 4)
#random order in column 2, i.e. a low correlation to the first columns
np.random.shuffle(A[:,2])
#flip column 3 to create a negative correlation with the first columns
A[:,3] = np.flipud(A[:,3])
#column 1 is unchanged, therefore positively correlated to column 0
df = pd.DataFrame(A)
print(df)
#establish a correlation matrix
corr = df.corr()
#retrieve index of pairs below a certain value
#use only the upper triangle with np.triu to filter for symmetric solutions
#use np.abs to take also negative correlation into account
res = np.argwhere(np.triu(np.abs(corr.values) <0.7))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[0 2]
 [1 2]
 [2 3]]
```

As expected, column 2 is the only one that is not correlated to any other, meaning, that all other columns are correlated with each other.

Comment: what the `np.triu` does?

Comment: Then, how to get the columnar data which are less correlated?

Comment: I also need index of the column which is less correlated to other columns?

Comment: As mentioned, [np.triu()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) prevents to have symmetric solutions. If col 0 is not correlated to col 2, then obviously col 2 is not correlated to col 0. To extract only one pair, I used `np.triu`. Remove it to see, what I mean.

Comment: The second question doesn't make sense. In the pair [0,2] column 0 is not correlated to column 2. Which number do you want to extract? Both are not correlated with each other.